# Selecting select statements into cells in the same row instead of on top of each other

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a query that illustrates the discrepancy between row count using this statement.

```
select count(*) from Donkey where Don is null
union
select count(Key) from Donkey
```

Now, I want to improve it by two and a half changes.

1. I want a third element that computes the difference between them.
2. I want the cells to be horizontally placed.
3. (Or 2½, really.) If possible, I want to learn how to do it without transposing.

My attempt on (1) failed due to syntax confusion. I tested a few different version, none of which produced anything other than errors.

```
select count(*) from Donkey where Don is null
union
select count(Key) from Donkey
union
(select count(*) from Donkey where Don is null
-
select count(Key) from Donkey)
```

My attempt on (2) failed of the same reason.

```
select(select ..., select ...)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First, just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when Don is null then 1 else 0 end) as cnt1,
       count(key) as cnt2
from Donkey ;
```

Then if you want the difference:

```
select sum(case when Don is null then 1 else 0 end) as cnt1,
       count(key) as cnt2,
       (sum(case when Don is null then 1 else 0 end) -
        count(key)
       ) as diff
from Donkey ;
```